# Cant get evet.charCode to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 divs that i need to put them only accepting numbers.
I have tried to append the "onkeypress" function but it still accepts numbers.
Is there anyone here that can help me out? I cant seem to find where the problem relies.

This is the code:

```
document.getElementById("cc-num").maxLength = 16;
document.getElementById("zip").maxLength = 5;
document.getElementById("cvv").maxLength = 3;
$("#cc-num").append("onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && 
event.charCode <= 57'");// makes the Card Number div only digit 
available.
$("#zip").append("onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && 
event.charCode <= 57'"); // makes the Zip div only digit available
$("#cvv").append("onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && 
event.charCode <= 57'"); // makes the cvv div only digit available.
```

Comment: Not sure you want to use `$(...).append(...)` to append an event listener. Since you are using jQuery, consider using the `.on()` syntax.

Comment: `$("#zip").append("onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && 
` not even close

Comment: Suggested reading for you. jQuery `.on` http://api.jquery.com/on/ which attaches event listeners. And the possible events https://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Answer (score 2):

In order to have access to the event, you need your `keypress` event to invoke a function that will have the event passed to it as an argument.

Additionally, don't use inline HTML event attributes (i.e. `onkeypress`). That's how event handlers were set up 25 years ago and for some God forsaken reason, will not go away. There are **[many reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991)** not to use them and instead follow modern, standards-based approaches.

```js
// Set up your event callbacks in JavaScript, not with inline HTML attributes.

// The function you supply as the callback will automatically
// recieve a reference to the event
$("#cc-num").on("keypress", function(evt){
 if(evt.charCode >= 48 && evt.charCode <= 57){
   console.log(evt.charCode);
 } else {
   evt.preventDefault();  // Cancel the event
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="cc-num">
```

By the way, if you use the HTML5 `input type="number"`, you won't need any of this code, as only numeric input is allowed in the first place.

```html
<input type="number">
```

Or, because you have a pattern, the HTML5 `pattern` attribute on a textbox with a regular expression for a credit card would do the trick:

```css
:valid { background-color:rgba(0,255,0,.3); }
:invalid { background-color:rgb(255,0,0,.3); }
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}">
```